# How to Set up Stripe Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments

For a point of reference, I've been following [this guide](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/guides/rails) on Stripe for Ruby on Rails. After completing it, I'm receiving this error:

```
Cannot charge a customer that has no active card
```

I'm now at my wits end...

I have stripe in my bundle. I ran `rails g controller payments`.

This is the payments controller I have set up:

```
class PaymentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :session_check

  def index
    redirect_to new_payment_path
  end

  def new
  end

  def create
    @amount = 900

    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
      :email => current_user.email,
      :card  => params[:stripetoken]
    )

    charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
      :customer    => customer.id,
      :amount      => @amount,
      :description => 'Rails Stripe customer',
      :currency    => 'cad'
    )

    redirect_to account_path
  rescue Stripe::CardError => e
    render text: e.message
  end
end
```

`:session_check` is a method inside the application controller:

```
def session_check
  redirect_to login_path unless current_user
end
```

In the routes I have `resources :payments`.

This is what I have in `config/initializers/stripe.rb`:

```
# For Runnning on Development or Test Environments:
# sandbox number is 4242 4242 4242 4242
# any three digit CVC
# expiry date must be in future

Rails.configuration.stripe = {
  :publishable_key => Rails.env.production? ? ENV['PUBLISHABLE_KEY'] : "pk_test_long_hash",
  :secret_key      => Rails.env.production? ? ENV['SECRET_KEY'] : "sk_test_another_long_hash"
}

Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]
```

Within `payments/new.html.erb` we have:

```
<h1 class="text-center"> Upgrade Today </h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="text-center">
      <%= form_tag payments_path do %>
        <article>
          <label class="amount">
            <span>Amount: $9.00</span>
          </label>
        </article>

        <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
                data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>"
                data-name="Site Using Stripe"
                data-description="One Month Subscription"
                data-amount="900"
                data-currency="cad"
                data-email="<%= current_user.email %>"
                data-allow-remember-me="true"></script>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And `payments/create.html.erb` is pretty simple. Stripe default:

```
<h2> Thanks, you paid <strong>$5.00</strong>!</h2>
```

**Key Question:** Why am I receiving `Cannot charge a customer that has no active card` when I process a test credit card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not an expert on this, but I do have a working app with String and in my Create method we have this line:

:card  => params[:stripetoken]

in the Stripe::Charge, and not in the Stripe::Customer
Which that makes sense to me, Customer can probably have more than one card, but each charge must be provided a unique card.

Here's what I have in my Payment model

```
  def save_with_payment(payment)
    if valid?
      Stripe::Charge.create(
        :amount => payment.amount*100, #amount in cents
        :currency => "usd",
        :card => stripe_card_token,
        :description => "description of payment");
      save
    end
    rescue Stripe::InvalidRequestError => e
    logger.error "Stripe error while creating customer: #{e.message}"
    errors.add :base, "There was a problem with your credit card."
    false
  end
```

Comment: It was a misspelling. Its `stripeToken` not `stripetoken`, but I wouldn't have seen this if you hadn't told me to look at the `card`, hence my +1. I'll also look to your payment model for inspiration. Merci.

Comment: Ah, yes I see that now. How frustrating these little misspellings can be sometimes.